# How to embed or get metdata from a link?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink

I am trying to make React Component where I like to display cards like which you see on Facebook or Linked In when you post some link.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You start with `fetch()` and parse the information from the return HTML, mainly in elements inside the `<head>`.

However, this is only going to work if the target site has super open CORS headers. Most sites don't, and for those cases you will need a server to do the fetching and perhaps parsing.